# Java Reflection. Access the value of a field

Tags: java, reflection, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to complete a program with Java Reflection. I have a problem with this part. I can not get the value of the field I am looking for.

```
Field [] fx = ArrayUtils.addAll(c.getDeclaredFields(),c.getFields());
for (int j = 0; i < fx.length; j++){
    System.out.println(fx[j].toString());
    if( fx[j].isAnnotationPresent(Searchable.class)){
        Searchable ann = fx[j].getAnnotation(Searchable.class);
        System.out.println(ann.field() + " " + fx[j].getGenericType());
        if (ann.field().equals(field)){
    System.out.println ("Found it!");
    try {
        fx[j].setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println((String)fx[j].get(c));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    break;
        }
    }
}
```

With this code I get this message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.String field
>   store.model.Book.publisher to java.lang.Class

Any idea how I can do it? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What is this piece of code supposed to do?

Comment: I just want to point out that those are some god aweful variable names. Giving them some more descriptive names might help you, or other people, figure out what's going on in there a lot easier.

Comment: The stack trace tells exactly what line that's happening on, and I don't think it's in this code. Note that (1) you don't need to cast to a `String` for `println` and (2) calling `toString()` is nearly always better than casting.

Comment: @Bono you are totally right. Thanks for the advice. I will try yo improve that in my future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line...

```
System.out.println((String)fx[j].get(c));
```

The variable c is of type Class and not of type Book. You need to pass get() an *instance* of Book.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you, that you try to instert a String object in to the field that store the Class object.

and it is probably here:

```
System.out.println((String)fx[j].get(c)); // the c is a Book.class, it should a Book instance object.
```